# JavaScript On-click

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, onclick

I have this document, which allows me to have a multi-choice selection questionnaire with progression on-click.

How do I go about having images in-place of the words here? (and still have the mechanic where, once the [image] is clicked, the next question is brought up)

I tried already some basic div manipulation with f.e the UL/H1 setting background images, but as you expect, this lead me to nothing of use.

I'm curious if it is because 'caption' needs to be something else.

```
            var questions = [
                {
                    caption: 'Question 1?',
                    answers: [
                        { caption: 'It sucks!' },
                        { caption: 'It rules!' }
                    ]
                }
```

The rest of my code in-progress found at:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rbzy6/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing something like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/Rbzy6/24/)

What I do is that I set as answers the name of the image:

```
var questions = [
        {
            caption: 'Question 1?',
            answers: [
                { caption: 'It sucks!' },
                { caption: 'It rules!' }
            ]
        },
        {
            caption: 'Question 2?',
            answers: [
                { caption: '_62880798_62880797.jpg' },
                { caption: '_62880035_62880034.jpg' }
            ]
        }
];
```

Then, after:

```
self.currentQuestion(questions[currentQuestionIndex]);
```

I add this jQuery code:

```
$('#lol').find('li').each(function() {
    var imgPath = 'http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/62880000/jpg/';
    var imgName = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<img src="'+imgPath+imgName+'" width="20" />');
});
```

I use the content of the `li` element (the answer) to get the name of the image and then I replace the content of the `li` element with an image tag (`<img src="" />`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Dim13i,
Firstly I notice that the images with this setup cannot be displayed on 'question 1' - is this fixable?
Secondly, did I thank you already? Haha
I also notice that this setup conflicts with the output of answers, which I did intend that part at least to be text. Any idea for a work-around on that?

Comment: I just thought, I could have a 'click to start' kind of button as the 'first question' - this could be a cheap fix.

Comment: And like this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/Rbzy6/27/) I've created a function `setImage()` and I call it in `$(document).ready()` and then in the same place as before.

Comment: You're a Hero, Dim13i!
Just tidied the code up a little, inlined the answers and added a third question. http://jsfiddle.net/Rbzy6/28/ 1 step from being perfect is now a better output response, though with this I guess I could just add a new output for each answer (if ans1 clicked, output x, if ans 2 output y)~
Though I should probably create a new thread about this if I can't manage it myself

Comment: Something like this
JS:
`function q1a1(){
document.getElementById( "output1" ).innerHTML += 'Just 1';
}
function q1a2(){
document.getElementById( "output1" ).innerHTML += '2 - 5';
}
function q1a3(){
document.getElementById( "output1" ).innerHTML += '6 or more';
}`
and then
HTML:
<li id="output1">

Comment: Yes, why not, or maybe using a `switch(answer){ case 1: str = 'Just1'; break; case 2: str = '2-5'; break; case 3: str = '6 or more'; break; default: break;} document.getElementById( "output1" ).innerHTML += str`.